# AngularJS- Check A value is undefined or null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay! New to AngularJS. Here is my controller code to check if a value is undefined or null.

```
var configId=$routeParams.confiId;
    angular.isUndefinedOrNull = function(configId){ return angular.isUndefined(configId) || configId === null};
    if(angular.isUndefinedOrNull) {
        alert(configId);
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
```

And it always alerts with `true`. 
So I tried alerting **configId**. If the value is there, it alerts the value otherwise it is alerting **undefined**. Not going to else part as condition is always true. What is wrong here?

Comment: try `if(angular.isUndefinedOrNull(configId))` instead

Comment: No. It is also not working

Comment: Sorry @KhanhTO it was working. I only replaced the if and alerted wrong. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if(angular.isUndefinedOrNull)` is basically checking to see if `angular.isUndefinedOrNull` is truthy. Since `angular.isUndefinedOrNull` is a function, this will always be true.

Try `if( angular.isUndefinedOrNull(configId) )`, which checks if the value returned by `angular.isUndefinedOrNull` is truthy. This will alert `true` if the value returned by `angular.isUndefinedOrNull()` is truthy, and false otherwise.

Comment: To add to @godfrzero's answer here, you also want to be aware that `function(configId) {...}` isn't passing `configId` in, it's declaring it as a new variable in the scope of that function.  You still need to pass it when you call the function.  So instead of `if( angular.isUndefinedOrNull() )` you want `if( angular.isUndefinedOrNull(configId) )`

Comment: ah it seems we had similar thoughts.  Good, all is well now.

Comment: angular.isUndefinedOrNull is really a function in AngularJS? What version? I can't see it in API Reference in AngularJS' site

Comment: @AlexCoroza Old question, but seems like it's a function iProgrammer defined and not a part of Angular. iProgrammer, please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @boi_echos I believe it's just `angular.isUndefined` now. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic javascript check like

```
if(nameOfVariable) //Returns false if variable has null or blank or undefined as value
{

} 
else
{

}
```

Cheers from [CheezyCode](http://www.cheezycode.com)

Comment: This is not useful if 0 or false are possible valid values of your variable.

Comment: @yms - Agreed with your comment.